# Redirect all website folders and files to the root of a new domain

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect all website including files that dont exist anymore to the root of the new domain.

Some examples:

- Olddomain.com should go to newdomain.com
- Olddomain.com/folder to newdomain.com
- Oldomain.com/anyfolder/anyfile.pdf to newdomain.com
- Olddomain.com/evenafile_that_doesnt_exists to newdomain.com

I was using

```
redirect 301 / newdomain.com
```

but this would require that the file exists in new domain with the exact path.

An extra challenge:

- Redirect all old html files to new php in same path
- Redirect all other files and directories with exact same path to newdomain.com where a page bot found error would appear in case path was incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^ http://newdomain.com/
```

That will redirect everything to the same place.

Comment: Thanks it worked :) I am so noob. It looks so easy. Is there anyway to check those commands like ^ and stuff? Is it possible to configure some conditions and then "else: your code"?